How to generate .bin executable file with MPLAB-X-IDE?
I am generating executable file using  MPLAB_X_IDE from Microchip with compiler is XC-16.
It generates executable files .hex and .elf. However, this time I need the binary executable file. Can anybody please tell me how to generate the .bin file from the .hex or .elf one and if this is possible with MPLAB-X-IDE or any of its plugs-in?

After hours of reaserch on the web, I found the way:
In MPLAB project properties window select "Building" and the tell the compiler to execute this macro after building:
${MP_CC_DIR}\xc16-objcopy -I ihex -O binary "${DISTDIR}/${PROJECTNAME}.${IMAGE_TYPE}.hex" "${DISTDIR}/${PROJECTNAME}.${IMAGE_TYPE}.bin"
The image shows how to do it:

That's it.
Now the issue is understand why the generated bin file is near 10 times bigger than the .hex file, but I will make another specific post for that, because I have not the slightest idea...
